# Input Cpf e telefone aceitar só numero

Tags: javascript, html, input

Como posso fazer para que os input cpf e telefone do meu formulário aceitem apenas números, usando javascript, tentei colocar o type="number" mas eu achei muito ruim, e dependendo do navegador do usuário não funciona, quero uma resposta com javascript se possível.

```
<input type="text" id="frmCpf" name="frmCpf" maxlength="11" size="11" placeholder="Somente números"></input>

<input type="text" id="frmNumero" name="frmNumero" size="20" maxlength="9" placeholder="Somente números"></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o *plugin* `JQuery` [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask). Com ele você consegue definir o formato dos dados de um `input`.

Para definir o formato do CPF, basta usar o seguinte código `jQuery`:

```js
$("#frmCpf").inputmask({
  mask: "999.999.999-99"
});
```

Cada `9` indica que nessa posição só pode ter valores no intervalo `[0, 9]`. Se não quiser os `.` e o `-`, basta remover eles da máscara.

Outra forma de usar o `InputMask` é direto no html, com o atributo `data-inputmask`.

```html
<input type="text" id="frmNumero" name="frmNumero" placeholder="Somente números" data-inputmask="'mask': '9', 'repeat': 10, 'greedy' : false"/>
```

Depois basta chamar `$("#frmNumero").inputmask();` no `JavaScript`.
A propriedade `repeat` indica quantas vezes a máscara vai se repetir. No caso do `input` acima, podemos inserir valores no intervalo `[0, 9]` um máximo de `10` vezes. Já a propriedade `greedy: false` faz com que o *plugin* exiba a menor máscara que ele conseguir.

É importante que você dê uma lida na [documentação](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) se for criar novas máscaras.

Segue um exemplo executando:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#frmCpf").inputmask({
    mask: "999.999.999-99"
  });
  
  $("#frmNumero").inputmask();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="frmCpf" name="frmCpf" placeholder="Somente números"/>

<input type="text" id="frmNumero" name="frmNumero" placeholder="Somente números" data-inputmask="'mask': '9', 'repeat': 10, 'greedy' : false"/>
```

> Se não estiver usando `JQuery`:

Você pode usar o [VanillaMasker](https://github.com/vanilla-masker/vanilla-masker).

Para definir o formato do CPF, basta usar `maskPattern`, como no código a seguir:

```js
VMasker(document.getElementById("frmCpf")).maskPattern("999.999.999-99");
```

A máscara funciona de forma semelhante ao que falei para o `InputMask`.

Para indicar que um campo é apenas numérico, basta usar o método `maskNumber`, como no código a seguir:

```js
VMasker(document.getElementById("frmNumero")).maskNumber();
```

Segue um exemplo usando o `VanillaMasker`:

```js
VMasker(document.getElementById("frmCpf")).maskPattern("999.999.999-99");
VMasker(document.getElementById("frmNumero")).maskNumber();
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vanilla-masker@1.1.1/build/vanilla-masker.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="frmCpf" name="frmCpf" placeholder="Somente números"/>

<input type="text" id="frmNumero" name="frmNumero" placeholder="Somente números" data-inputmask="'mask': '9', 'repeat': 10, 'greedy' : false"/>
```

Comment: Será que ele está utilizando jQuery?

Comment: Obrigado por lembrar. Adicionei uma biblioteca sem `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar esta função javascript abaixo:

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

[Resposta retirada deste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox)